Arm cpu nested virtualization, How can I make VCPU start from EL2？
Recently I've been testing Arm architecture nested virtualization. Since I don't have actual Armv8.4 CPUs, I used QEMU-9.0.0-rc2 to simulate an Arm chip. According to the QEMU changelog, support for FEAT_ECV, FEAT_NV, and FEAT_NV2 has been added in QEMU-9.0.0. Additionally, I used linux-6.8.4's KVM as the Hypervisor. Below is the command I used to start the outer QEMU:
./qemu-9.0.0-rc2/bin/qemu-system-aarch64 -nographic -machine virt-9.0,secure=on,virtualization=on,gic_version=3 \
    -cpu max \
    -smp 4 -m 4G \
    -bios ./trusted-firmware-a/build/qemu/debug/bl1.bin \
    -semihosting-config enable=on,target=native \
    -kernel ./linux-6.8.4/arch/arm64/boot/Image \
    -initrd ./buildroot-kvm/output/images/rootfs.cpio \
    -append "kvm-arm.mode=nested" \

This was able to boot into the system normally and printed:
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Virtualization Host Extensions
[    0.190843] CPU features: detected: Enhanced Counter Virtualization
[    0.191057] CPU features: detected: Enhanced Counter Virtualization (CNTPOFF)
[    0.191520] CPU features: detected: Enhanced Virtualization Traps
[    0.193408] CPU features: detected: Nested Virtualization Support
[    1.271492] kvm [1]: nv: 477 coarse grained trap handlers
[    1.281075] kvm [1]: nv: 668 fine grained trap handlers
[    1.281840] kvm [1]: IPA Size Limit: 52 bits
[    1.283506] kvm [1]: GICv3: no GICV resource entry
[    1.284258] kvm [1]: disabling GICv2 emulation
[    1.285290] kvm [1]: GIC system register CPU interface enabled
[    1.287004] kvm [1]: vgic interrupt IRQ9
[    1.288348] kvm [1]: VHE mode initialized successfully

Then, I tried to start a virtual machine inside using QEMU with KVM acceleration with the following command:
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -accel kvm -cpu host -smp 1 -kernel tiny_Image_6.8.4 -initrd tiny_rootfs.cpio -nographic

This led to an exception [  197.871251] Internal error: Oops - Undefined instruction: 0000000002000000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP. I found that the error occurred in the timer_restore_state function in arch/arm64/kvm/arch_timer.c, where the set_cntpoff function was trying to write a value to the CNTPOFF_EL2 register, but I'm not sure why this happened.
Additionally, when I replaced the command to start the outer QEMU with -cpu neoverse_n2 or -cpu neoverse_v1, it only printed:
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Virtualization Host Extensions
[    0.189302] CPU features: detected: Enhanced Virtualization Traps
[    0.190418] CPU features: detected: Nested Virtualization Support
[    1.272526] kvm [1]: nv: 477 coarse grained trap handlers
[    1.273213] kvm [1]: IPA Size Limit: 48 bits
[    1.275016] kvm [1]: GICv3: no GICV resource entry
[    1.275717] kvm [1]: disabling GICv2 emulation
[    1.276642] kvm [1]: GIC system register CPU interface enabled
[    1.278780] kvm [1]: vgic interrupt IRQ9
[    1.280100] kvm [1]: VHE mode initialized successfully

Then, I tried to start a virtual machine inside again, and it was able to boot into the second-level virtual machine normally. However, KVM wasn't initialized, and it showed [   14.130576] kvm [1]: HYP mode not available. I believe this is because the VCPU didn't start from EL2. How can I make the VCPU start from EL2?
Finally, I found that the system_supported_vcpu_features function uses the KVM_VCPU_VALID_FEATURES macro, where
#define KVM_VCPU_MAX_FEATURES 7
#define KVM_VCPU_VALID_FEATURES (BIT(KVM_VCPU_MAX_FEATURES) - 1)

#define KVM_ARM_VCPU_HAS_EL2        7 /* Support nested virtualization */

Here, KVM_VCPU_VALID_FEATURES cannot cover the newly added KVM_VCPU_VALID_FEATURES features. Is this a BUG?
